# Laravel updateOrcreate missing value

Tags: php, laravel

I do parsing matches for DotA 2. Through a third-party API, I get current, future and past matches. But the problem how i understand, it's `updateOrCreate` function does not work. When parsing starts, it saves the values, but does not update the current ones. Here is an example of the answer that I get https://pastebin.com/KCcG6rJc, in this answer there is what teams are playing now, there are `match_id` of teams, if the teams are competing with each other, this value is the same. Using the example of this parsing result, I received the following record in the Database:

The `maches table`, the `match_id` value got there - `560004`, that's right. But in the `teams table`, where these commands are indicated, match_id is null.

At my parser i has this code:

```
foreach ($live_matches as $live) {

    if ($live->tournament_id != $tournament->id) {
        continue;
    }

    $filtered_matches[] = $live;

    foreach ($teams as &$team) {
        if (false !== strpos($live->slug, $team->slug)) {
            $team->match_id = $live->id;
            $logo = $team->image_url;
            var_dump($team);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

`var_dump($team); exit;` say me:

```
object(stdClass)#1222 (8) {
  ["acronym"]=>
  string(8) "ThunderP"
  ["id"]=>
  int(2671)
  ["image_url"]=>
  string(93) "https://cdn.pandascore.co/images/team/image/2671/87033C79D6D1A70A66941BC8649EA5988D74582C.png"
  ["location"]=>
  string(2) "PE"
  ["modified_at"]=>
  string(20) "2020-04-30T01:51:51Z"
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "Thunder Predator"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(16) "thunder-predator"
  ["match_id"]=>
  int(560004)
}
```

i.e. I get `match_id`, but at database it's not add.

And here is my full function, which update or create:

```
public function saveUpdate(int $tournament_id, array $tournament_teams, string $full_name, array $matches)
{
    $tournament = Tournament::updateOrCreate([
        'tournament_id' => $tournament_id,
        'league_name'   => $full_name
    ]);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if ($match->status == 'not_started') {
            $status = 0;
        }
        if ($match->status == 'running') {
            $status = 1;
        }
        if ($match->status == 'finished') {
            $status = 2;
        }
        $team = Tournament_teams::where('team_id', $match->winner_id)->first();

        Tournament_matches::updateOrCreate([
            'name'       => $match->name,
            'started_at' => Carbon::parse("$match->begin_at,")->setTimezone('Europe/Berlin'),
            'ended_at'   => $match->end_at,
            'winner_id'  => $team->id ?? null,
            'status'     => $status,
            'match_id'   => $match->id,
            'live'       => $match->live_url,
        ]);
    }

    foreach ($tournament_teams as $team) {
        Tournament_teams::updateOrCreate([
            'tournaments_id' => $tournament->id,
            'team'           => $team->name,
            'slug'           => $team->slug,
            'logo'           => $team->image_url,
            'team_id'        => $team->id,
        ], [
            'match_id'       => $team->match_id ?? null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

For example, if I delete 1 column value from the `teams` table and start parsing, then the value in this column will not be created. That is, it creates data, but does not update.

And now teams with `match_id 560334` are playing and the `tournament_teams` table doesn’t have such `match_id`, I searched for playing teams by name and found that there are 1 of the playing teams in the database 3 times in a row. That is, one record has `match_id = null`, the others of the same `match_id` commands have old ones. For some reason, the data on the current is not updated and empty values are received in the database, although 50% of the values are. Here is screenshot with highlighted commands for which for example data is not updated: [image: Screenshot]

Where could my mistake be? Why does `var_dump` pass me `match_id`, but this value does not get into the database? Where could my mistake be? I use Laravel 5.1. If you need to clarify any details - ask, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrongly the `updateOrCreate()` method.

As the [documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods):

---

> You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists.

```php
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

If I understood well your problem, you are doing it in the opposite way:

```php
Tournament_teams::updateOrCreate([
    'match_id'       => $team->match_id ?? null,
], [
    'tournaments_id' => $tournament->id,
    'team'           => $team->name,
    'slug'           => $team->slug,
    'logo'           => $team->image_url,
    'team_id'        => $team->id,
]);
```

Also, for this you don't need to use `updateOrCreate()` but `firstOrCreate()` for example:

```php
$tournament = Tournament::firstOrCreate([
    'tournament_id' => $tournament_id,
    'league_name'   => $full_name
]);
```

PS: If it is possible, I recommend you to use a newer Laravel version.

Comment: i will update to newer version within 1 week, I make by your example, but a lot of data is lost at `Tournament_teams` i mean, i received only with `match_id`, where `match_id null` i don't received teams, but now 2 live matches, and i don't receive at my table 

Comment: Ups, sorry. My bad. :( With the information you provided your code is a bit abstract. I thought the problem could be in the `updateOrCreate` method. The most important point is, do you know how does it work? If you undo the changes, you table is filled again?

Comment: do not worry, all is good :), yes, if i undo changes, table filled again. let me try to discribe problem. now there is a game of 2 teams of `Alliance` and `NiP`, they have `match_id` = 561520, in` tournament_matches` this match is with the same `match_id`, but in `tournament_teams` this `match_id` is null. if i search in the database `Alliance`, I get 4 results with an empty` match_id` and 4 results `NiP` with empty `match_id` it's main problem

Comment: What is `Alliance` and `NiP`? Anyway, sorry but I don't understand 100% your problem. I would need a UML representation or something. My advice is first to check if the `tournament_teams` are filled and are correct, finally, do your logic and fill the `tournament_matches` and so on. Try with dummy data and investigate. You could try with raw SQL queries `(DB::select())`, once it works, I suggest you switch to using the Eloquent model. Cheers! :)